# find rows with same values in mulitple columns with ID's

Tags: postgresql

i have a relatively big table, with a lot of columns and rows.
Among them i have ID, longitude and latitude.
I would like to have a list of ID's which have the same coordinates (latitude and longitude)
something like this

```
ID¦latitude¦longitude¦number

1 ¦   12.12¦    34.54¦1

12¦   12.12¦    34.54¦1

52¦   12.12¦    34.54¦1


3 ¦   56.08¦   -45.87¦1

67¦   56.08¦   -45.87¦1
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a "helper" column to the end where you concatenate the longitude and the latitude. For example paste into row 2 in that column `=B2&C2` and then drag it down. Then you can use `countif` to count the instances of each occurrence.

Comment: Better yet, he could create a view that contains only IDs with same lat and long. You could create this with a simple WHERE clause.

Comment: What is it? Excel or Postgres?

Comment: the table is big, over 65000 rows... postgres is better @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Ralph via postgres i get the number of occuring pair, samo coordinates, i just can figure out how to get the ID's, and the number of repeating for each combination

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know PostgreSQL. Hence, I offered a solution in Excel. Yet, I have to agree with anybody saying that a solution in PostgreSQL would be much better (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

You can either use an EXISTS query:

```
select *
from the_table t1
where exists (select 1
              from the_table t2
              where t1.id <> t2.id
                and (t1.latitude, t1.longitude) = (t2.latitude, t2.longitude))
order by latitude, longitude;
```

or a window function:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
           count(*) over (partition by latitude, longitude) as cnt
    from the_table t
) t
where cnt > 1
order by latitude, longitude;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ITKJ70005

Comment: – I was about to post WINDOW function example, but you got it first :) For this case WINDOW function should perform way better and if need to speed it up then ORDER BY is optional to drop if not required for a end result.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.latitude, t.longitude, grp.tot
FROM 
   your_table t INNER JOIN (
        SELECT latitude, longitude, count(*) AS tot
        FROM your_table
        GROUP BY latitude, longitude
        HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) grp ON (t.latitude = grp.latitude AND t.longitude = grp.longitude);
```

Or to get duplicates for lat/lng:

```
    SELECT
        latitude, longitude, 
        array_agg(id ORDER BY id) AS ids
    FROM
        place
    GROUP BY
        latitude, longitude
    HAVING
        count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what would be the solution in PostgreSQL if the *list* should be a concatenation of IDs after the latitude and longitude (as I did in my solution below for a T-SQL based solution)? For a visual example of what I mean you can look here: https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: @Ralph it's possible to use `array_agg` or `string_agg` functions

Comment: @Ralph I added example to answer.